# How to activate/enable interactors

Tags: java

I am not able to interact with the text field and the button, meaning when I click on them nothing happens.

It's my first try with java interactions after watching lectures 20 and 21 of iTunesU cs016a course.

I expected at least to be able to write something in the text field.
I am using Eclipse Helios on a Mac. The program compiles without warnings.

I have rewritten it several times, added some graphic and mouse interaction on the 
upper part and it worked quite well. I just can not understand why the button and the text field are not working.

What am I missing? Thank you for any hint.

The output is:

[program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foDjw.png)

My code is:

```
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;
import acmx.export.javax.swing.JButton;
import acmx.export.javax.swing.JLabel;
import acmx.export.javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Interactors extends GraphicsProgram {

    private static final int WIDTH = 1000;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 500;

    private static final long serialVersionUID      = 1L;
    private static final String NAME_LABEL_TEXT     = "Name";
    private static final int NAME_COLUMN_SIZE       = 40;
    private static final String NAME_DEFAULT_VALUE  = "Program";
    private static final String ADD_BUTTON_TEXT     = "Add";

    public void init() {

        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        add(new JLabel(NAME_LABEL_TEXT), SOUTH);
        add(new JTextField(NAME_DEFAULT_VALUE, NAME_COLUMN_SIZE), SOUTH);
        add(new JButton(ADD_BUTTON_TEXT), SOUTH);

        addActionListeners();
        addMouseListeners();
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for - can you fill us in on what `addActionListeners()` and `addMouseListeners()` does, or what they are supposed to do?

Comment: When the program runs, I want the user to be able to change the default text in the text field (which is "Program"), but it's not event possible to put the cursor on it... `addActionListeners()` and `addMouseListeners()` are part of [acm.program.Program](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/program/Program.html#addActionListeners()) and they may be commented out for now, it does not change my problem.

Comment: If you are overriding default behavior of the mouse listeners and / or action listeners it could cause that problem, but its impossible to guess unless you can show the code for those methods.

Comment: I didn't override those methods, I just invoke them. I already posted all the code I wrote (I need to write more, of course, but since buttons and other objects are not working I wanted to fix the problem before continuing with other code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem running the program using `Run > Run As > Java Application` instead of `Run > Run As > Java Applet`

I do not understand the difference and previously I always run the program using the button (the green round one, with a white arrow) which apparently always runs as  Applet.